# Multiple errors involving array subtypes

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>


using namespace std;


float writethread1(float storageptr, uint64_t storageexpptr, uint64_t num3, uint64_t counter, uint64_t exp){
//Printing the first half of numbers that the user requested.
counter = 0;
exp = 0;
exp = storageexpptr[counter];
//Printing numbers that do have e<3 at the end.
while (counter < 0.5 * num3){
    if (exp < 3){
        ofstream fileout;
        fileout.open ("fibonacci.txt", ios_base::app);
        fileout << fixed << "#" << counter << ": " << storageptr[counter] << "\n";
        counter += 1;
    }
//Printing numbers that do have e3> at the end.
    else{
        ofstream fileout;
        fileout.open ("fibonacci.txt", ios_base::app);
        fileout << fixed << "#" <<counter<< ": " << storageptr[counter] << "e" << storageptr[counter] << "\n";
        counter+=1;
    }
}
}

float writethread2(float storageptr, uint64_t storageexpptr, uint64_t num3, uint64_t counter, uint64_t exp){
//Printing the second half of numbers that the user requested.
counter = 0.5 * num3 +1;
exp = storageptr[counter];
//Printing numbers that do have e<3 at the end.
while(counter < num3){
    if (exp < 3){
        ofstream fileout;
        fileout.open ("fibonacci.txt", ios_base::app);
        fileout << fixed << "#" << counter << ": " << storageptr[counter] << "\n";
        counter += 1;
    }
//Printing numbers that do have e3> at the end.
    else{
        ofstream fileout;
        fileout.open ("fibonacci.txt", ios_base::app);
        fileout << fixed << "#" <<counter<< ": " << storageptr[counter] << "e" << storageexpptr[counter] << "\n" ;
        counter+=1;
    }
}
}

int main(){
//Declaring some variables.
float *storageptr;
uint64_t *storageexpptr;
float num1 = 0;
float num2 = 1;
uint64_t num3;
uint64_t counter = 1;
uint64_t exp = 0;
//User input to determine how many numbers the program generates.
cout << "How many numbers do you want to generate?" << endl;
cin >> num3;
vector <uint64_t> storageexp(num3);
vector <float> storage(num3);
storageexpptr = &storageexp;
storageptr = &storage;
//Calculator
while (counter<num3) {
    if (counter %2 == 0) {
        num1+=num2;
        storage[counter] = num1;
        storageexp[counter] =exp;
        counter+=1;
    }
    else{
        num2+=num1;
        storage[counter] = num2;
        storageexp[counter] =exp;
        counter+=1;
    }
    if( num1>1000) {
        num1/=1000;
        num2/=1000;
        exp+=2;
    }
    else if(num2>1000) {
              num1=num1/1000;
              num2=num2/1000;
              exp+=3;
    }

}

cout << "Calculation complete. Writing to file." << endl;
//Print to file preperations.
//Spawning a couple of threads.
thread thread1 (writethread1);
thread thread2 (writethread2);

}
```

Compiler output:

```
main.cpp||In function 'float writethread1(float, uint64_t, uint64_t, uint64_t, uint64_t)':|
main.cpp|15|error: invalid types 'uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}[uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}]' for array subscript|
main.cpp|21|error: invalid types 'float[uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}]' for array subscript|
main.cpp|28|error: invalid types 'float[uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}]' for array subscript|
main.cpp|28|error: invalid types 'float[uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}]' for array subscript|
main.cpp||In function 'float writethread2(float, uint64_t, uint64_t, uint64_t, uint64_t)':|
main.cpp|37|error: invalid types 'float[uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}]' for array subscript|
main.cpp|43|error: invalid types 'float[uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}]' for array subscript|
main.cpp|50|error: invalid types 'float[uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}]' for array subscript|
main.cpp|50|error: invalid types 'uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}[uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}]' for array subscript|
main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
main.cpp|70|error: cannot convert 'std::vector<long long unsigned int>*' to 'uint64_t* {aka long long unsigned int*}' in assignment|
main.cpp|71|error: cannot convert 'std::vector<float>*' to 'float*' in assignment|
```

The goal with that code was to print out the values of 2 arrays, whose value was determined in the main function. I attempted to use pointers to refer to the arrays and pull their values using the pointers. Compiler complained, never got far with it. I don't understand the information that the compiler has given me, essentially. Any help interpreting it would be appreciated. Or, if you have a solution to it, please provide that and what lead you to that conclusion.

Compiler output after making the changes suggested:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\functional||In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*())(float*, long long unsigned int*, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int)>':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\thread|137|required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(float*, long long unsigned int*, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int); _Args = {}]'| 
FIBONACCI\main.cpp|103|required from here|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\functional|1665|error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*())(float*, long long unsigned int*, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int)>'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\functional|1695|error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*())(float*, long long unsigned int*, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int)>'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Please include the releavant code and compiler output here

Comment: Edited. Unsure of if that will suffice or if more is needed.

Comment: With the `[]` operator, one operand must be an array or a pointer. But you write `storageptr[counter]` where those are two numbers.

Comment: I'm trying to point to a cell in the array "storage" using that. The number of the cell is equal to the value of "counter" at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeatedly using a float and a uint64_t parameter as arrays on lines 15, 21, 28, 37, 43, 50.  I cannot be sure, but based on the definitions of the calling parameters in your main(), I think you intended the corresponding parameters to your writethreadN functions to look like:

```
float writethread1(float* storageptr, uint64_t* storageexpptr, uint64_t num3, uint64_t counter, uint64_t exp){
```

Also, you are not returning a value in those functions even though they have a return type of float rather than void, which some compilers may not like (after you have repaired the parameters).

Finally, on lines 70 and 71, you are attempting to take the address of a vector and assign it to a pointer, when you probably meant to do something like this:

```
storageexpptr = storageexp.data();
storageptr = storage.data();
```

And your code to spawn the threads doesn't appear to be right, because you are specifying thread handler functions that take five parameters each, but not specifying what those parameters are when you create the actual thread objects.

Do you need a wait loop in your main() for when the threads complete?  I work in so many languages now, that I can't keep track of which require that and which don't, but I wanted to mention it in case you fix all of the problems and nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot! As far as a wait loop goes.... I'm unsure on that. How would one go about writing a wait loop? Also, I'm running into this new thing. I edited the main post to reflect what happens now once I make the changes you suggest.

Comment: The new thing you mention is caused by how you are creating the threads, which I mentioned in the second-to-last paragraph in my answer.  I think you need to specify the parameters to pass to the thread handler functions when you are creating your threads, since the std::_Bind_simple and std::thread error descriptions both indicate that they are expecting parameters that match your writethread parameter lists.